# Datatable Filtering & Row Highlighting not working together

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a data table that has row highlighting and table sorting, but when i run the two pieces of code, the one for the Highlighting and the one for the filtering i get an error.

I understand why i get the error but no matter how i write the code, once i join them together the code stops working, below is my javascipt code and a link to the jsfiddle example.

```
  $(document).ready( function () {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
"aoColumns": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    { "sType": "date-uk" },
    { "sType": "date-uk" },
    { "sType": "date-uk" },
    null,
    null,
    null
 ]
 });

jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"date-uk-pre": function ( a ) {
var ukDatea = a.split('/');
return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
},

 "date-uk-asc": function ( a, b ) {
 return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
 },

 "date-uk-desc": function ( a, b ) {
 return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
 }

 });

fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
   if (aData[3] == "PV PLUS") {
       $(nRow).addClass('highlight');
   }
   if (aData[3] == "ECO1") {
       $(nRow).addClass('highlight1');
   }
   if (aData[3] == "ECO2") {
       $(nRow).addClass('highlight2');
   }
  } 
 });
```

Link

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxdofh8e/4/)

Edited code

```
 $(document).ready( function () {
 $('#example').dataTable( {
"aoColumns": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    { "sType": "date-uk" },
    { "sType": "date-uk" },
    { "sType": "date-uk" },
    null,
    null,
    null
   ]
  });

  jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "date-uk-pre": function ( a ) {
  var ukDatea = a.split('/');
   return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    },

    "date-uk-asc": function ( a, b ) {
     return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
   },

     "date-uk-desc": function ( a, b ) {
     return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
   }

  });
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
   if (aData[3] == "PV PLUS") {
       $(nRow).addClass('highlight');
   }
   if (aData[3] == "ECO1") {
       $(nRow).addClass('highlight1');
   }
   if (aData[3] == "ECO2") {
       $(nRow).addClass('highlight2');
     }
    } 
 });
});
```

So i have updated my code and it doesn't error anymore, however the highlighting doesn't work either now.

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: oh you have a straight up syntax error. `fnRowCallback: function ...` needs to be inside of an object literal

Comment: I had the code originally in an object as shown in the edit above, but everytime i ran the code it said that there was an error and refered me to the  datatables website which said i couldn't call the request twice

Comment: why not just add it to the first initializer after `aoColumns`

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct code is shown below:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "date-uk-pre": function(a) {
        var ukDatea = a.split('/');
        return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
    },
    "date-uk-asc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "date-uk-desc": function(a, b) {
        return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        'columnDefs': [
            { 'type': 'date-uk', 'targets': [6,7,8] }
        ],
        'rowCallback': function( row, data, index ){
            if (data[3] == "PV PLUS") {
                $(row).addClass('highlight');
            }
            if (data[3] == "ECO1") {
                $(row).addClass('highlight1');
            }
            if (data[3] == "ECO2") {
                $(row).addClass('highlight2');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxdofh8e/10/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Brilliant Thank you